# Proper curved labeling of polygon objects in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

Trying to smooth and nice labeling for polygon features (lakes and seas, data from Naturalearthdata).  But curved labeling does not work properly (I'm trying to achieve to label inside in the center of the polygon).
I know about the manual approach (drawing curved lines manually), but this is not the case (there are more than 1000 objects), so it takes too long.
I have attached a screenshot of the current result.
Maybe there is some plugin to do this or just set some specific properties to achieve this?

[image]

Additional image
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can try to work with Geometrygenerator which you can use to place your labes. In this example the Polygon geometry of the lakes is converted into a line with the negative buffered lake polygon:

```
boundary(buffer($geometry,-0.2))
```

May be you should make the buffer value related to the size (area) of the lake, for example with a rule based labeler.

[image]

Comment: When I tried this expression "boundary(buffer($geometry,-0.2))" I  got my QGIS  3.28.8 crushed.

Comment: And as I see, there are not all objects labeled from this expression, Nipigon Lake for example (north of Superior Lake).

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, you should make a rule-based labeler to handle different sizes of lakes, smaller lakes should be buffered with smaller values. The example posted above uses lat-lon values which is not the best choice, that was quick drawn to explain how to do it.

Comment: What kind of expression it could be? Something like this?:                                                                                           CASE
    WHEN "scalerank" = '1' THEN boundary(buffer($geometry,-0.6))
    WHEN "scalerank" = '2' THEN boundary(buffer($geometry,-0.5))
    WHEN "scalerank" = '3' THEN boundary(buffer($geometry,-0.4))
    WHEN "scalerank" = '4' THEN boundary(buffer($geometry,-0.3))
    WHEN "scalerank" = '5' THEN boundary(buffer($geometry,-0.2))
 END

Comment: if possible I would switch from lat-lon to metrics, but in general that looks good

Comment: Well, must say it's a pretty tricky solution, It seems to be partly working now, but now I can't set different font sizes for different scale ranks of lakes in the expression settings. The expression is right, but the fonts don't changes. Is there any way to fix this? I attached a new image of what I got now.

Comment: Update, the problem was in font properties (need to mess up with font sizes, angles, position, etc).